# How should I interpret a neural network that won't overfit?

Tags: neural-network, weka

I'm running some experiments on various classification datasets using WEKA's MultilayerPerceptron implementation. I was expecting to be able to observe overfitting as the number of train iterations (epochs) increased. However, despite letting the number of epochs grow fairly large (15k), I haven't seen it yet. How should I interpret this? Note that I'm not achieving 100% accuracy on the train or test sets so it's not that the problem is too simplisitic.

Some ideas I came up with are:

- I simply haven't waited long enough
- My network isn't complex enough to overfit
- My data doesn't really contain any noise but isn't descriptive enough for the target function
- I'm not using the Evaluation class in WEKA correctly
- My test data set has leaked in to my train set (I'm 99% sure it hasn't, though)

I'm running the following after each epoch (I modified MultilayerPerceptron to have an "EpochListener", but no other changes than that:

```
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
    eval.evaluateModel(ann, train);
    System.out.println(eval.pctCorrect());
    eval.evaluateModel(ann, test);
    System.out.println(eval.pctCorrect());
```

The train accuracy seems to plateau and I never see the test accuracy start to decrease substantially.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their comments. I wish I could accept all of the answers. After experimenting with reduced amounts of data I was able to witness overfitting. Also, even in my original experiments there may have been slight amounts of overfitting but it was much more subtle than I was expecting. So I guess my takeaway as a ML student is that although ANNs are prone to overfitting due to their flexibility, that doesn't mean it's easy or even possible to demonstrate depending on the amount of training data and network complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would the simplest plausible explanation not be that your train and test sets are balanced, and the feedback is stable, so nothing changes any longer? In other words, you have converged on the optimal result you can obtain for this problem with this data and this technology.

A simple test would be to *reduce* the training data substantially, and see if that produces overfitting (which would manifest as  close to 100% accuracy on the reduced training set, lousy accuracy on the test set).

Answer (score 2):

Can you describe your network and data a little bit? How many dimensions are your data? How many hidden layers, with how many nodes in your network?

My initial thought is that if you have a fairly simple data set, with a good amount of data, and a fairly simple network,  your network just won't have enough alternative hypothesis to overfit.

Answer (score 0):

As Taylor Phebus has pointed out, it may be hard to know without understanding the parameters of the Neural Notwork.

Have you adjusted the Learning Rate, Momentum and Epoch Size parameters?  Perhaps adding more hidden layer neurons may assist also in causing the neural network to overfit if this number is small.  The activation function and number of training runs could also help.